# How to setup webapp specific parameter for virtual host in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost

I would like to have this setup in Tomcat:

1. virtual host
2. webapp resides directly in ROOT and is autoDeployed
3. I need to pass some specific webapp parameter in Tomcat configuration (outside war)

1st I have this scenario:

```
  <Host name="my.domain.com" appBase="vhosts/my.domain.com" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
  </Host>
```

and `ROOT.war` in directory `$CATALINA_BASE/vhosts/my.domain.com/`

-> everything works fine

2nd now I try to add the context parameter

```
  <Host name="my.domain.com" appBase="vhosts/my.domain.com" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Context docBase="/" reloadable="true">
              <Parameter name="serverRole" value="dev" override="true"/>
        </Context>
  </Host>
```

-> app is no more accessible by `my.domain.com` (404)

-> I also tried to move the Context from Host to separate `ROOT.xml` file residing in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/my.domain.com/`  but with no success

Actually I don't know what to set for path or `docBase`, but it seems that I am lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

1. I removed the docBase attribute completely (setting it to empty didn't work !)
2. I moved the Context from server.xml into ROOT.xml as described above (it's actually recommended by Tomcat team)

Final words,
the thing why it didn't come to my mind to remove the docBase attribute at the beginning was that I thought that it was mandatory attribute as it is marked bold in the Tomcat's documentation.

JoeK